# Android Emulator: Not able to get Proxy settings to work globaly across all apps

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, http-proxy

I have encountered difficulties while attempting to run all apps behind an HTTP proxy. I have tried using the "-http-proxy" option, but it appears to be ineffective/buggy with certain proxy providers. Additionally, I have explored the APN method, but unfortunately, it does not enable the proxy to function globally for all apps.

Could anyone kindly provide suggestions or alternative approaches to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Emulator Proxy Settings:
In the Android emulator, you can try setting the proxy directly within the device's network settings:

Open the Settings app on the emulator.
Go to "Network & internet" or "Wi-Fi" settings.
Find the active network connection (usually labeled as Wi-Fi) and tap on it.
Look for the "Proxy" or "Advanced" settings option.
Configure the proxy settings according to your requirements (e.g., enter the proxy hostname/IP and port).
Save the settings and restart the emulator.
System Proxy Settings:
Another approach is to configure the proxy settings at the system level within the Android emulator:

Open the Settings app on the emulator.
Go to "Network & internet" or "Wi-Fi" settings.
Find the active network connection (usually labeled as Wi-Fi) and tap on it.
Tap on "Proxy" or "Advanced" settings.
Choose "Manual" or "Proxy Auto-Config" and enter the proxy details.
Save the settings and restart the emulator.
Proxy Configuration with a PAC File:
You can try using a Proxy Auto-Configuration (PAC) file to configure the proxy settings for the emulator:

Host the PAC file on a web server accessible to the emulator.
Open the Settings app on the emulator.
Go to "Network & internet" or "Wi-Fi" settings.
Find the active network connection (usually labeled as Wi-Fi) and tap on it.
Tap on "Proxy" or "Advanced" settings.
Choose "Automatic" and enter the URL of the PAC file.
Save the settings and restart the emulator.
Third-Party Emulator:
If the built-in Android emulator doesn't meet your needs, you can consider using a third-party emulator that offers better proxy support: